# dataset.value returning "[object Object]" rather than the actual object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to dynamically create options for a select from objects passed from the controller to the DOM. As part of the options, I need to pass properties of these objects as data-values. I can build the select fine, but cannot build the dataset.value correctly. Currently, my code is this:

```
select.name = "indicator_id_option_" + count;
select.id = "indicator_" + count;
select.setAttribute("onchange", "if (typeof(this.selectedIndex) != '--'){ addNewSelect(this)}");
indicators.forEach(function(indicator){
    var optionToAppend = document.createElement('option');
    optionToAppend.text = indicator.pk;
    var dataVal = {"id": indicator.pk, "timePeriod": indicator.fields.time_period};
    optionToAppend.dataset.value = Object.assign({}, dataVal);
    console.log(optionToAppend.dataset.value);
    select.appendChild(optionToAppend);
});
```

`Indicators` is an object of objects that I can iterate through fine, and can call the properties of with no issues. When I build my options, the option text displays correctly (the `indicator.pk`), but the data-value is displaying as `[object Object]`. When `console.log`ging the `dataset.value` I get `[object Object]`, when logging `JSON.stringify(dataset.value)` I get `"[object Object]"`. When I log out `dataVal` I get the actual object that I can access the properties of - `Object {id: 92235, timePeriod: "annual"}`. I have tried a direct assign - `optionToAppend.dataset.value = dataVal` - and the option above and nothing is creating the object correctly. Any guidance?

Comment: > Any guidance?

In DOM properties there are lot of getter/setter functions, which forces to convert type and/or values. In current case, `value` forced to be string, by design of `dataset` object.

DOM model allows you to add custom tags into object, and since it is not frozen, you can easily append target property with natural object.

Comment: `optionToAppend.dataset.value = JSON.stringify(dataVal);` ?

Comment: @JohanKarlsson - that seemed to have worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears when you set  `optionToAppend.dataset.value`, implicitly converting your object to a string.

You can solve this by using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), which converts the object to a JSON string:

```
optionToAppend.dataset.value = JSON.stringify(dataVal);
```

Comment: I was assigning JSON to a dataset value and this also fixed it, when you want to get it back you just do `JSON.parse(optionToAppend.dataset.value)`